# Make a client to connect to a ftp server

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, client

I'm trying to do a client in C witch connect to a FTP server, but there is some problems i can't solve, when i launch my client the connexion to the server works then i enter my login ("USER login"), I receive the answer from the server which ask to me my password and when i try to enter it i have this answer : "500 Invalid command: try being more creative". I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with select() function or something else.
Thanks for help.

```
void    receive_and_send(int sock)
{
   char buffer[1024];
   char buffer2[1024];
   fd_set rfds;
   int retval;
   int nb_recv;
   int nb_read;
   char *cpybuffer;

   memset(buffer, '\0', 1024);
   memset(buffer2, '\0', 1024);
   while (42)
    {
      FD_ZERO(&rfds);
      FD_SET(0, &rfds);
      FD_SET(sock, &rfds);                                                                              
      if ((retval = select(sock + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
          printf("Error with select\n");
          exit(0);
        }
      if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rfds))
        {
          if ((nb_recv = read(sock, buffer, 1024 - 1)) < 0)
            exit(0);
          if (nb_recv < 1024)
            {
              buffer[nb_recv] = '\0';
              fprintf(stderr, "[%s]", buffer);
              memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
            }
        }
     if (FD_ISSET(0, &rfds))
        {                                                                         
          nb_read = read(0, buffer2, 1024);
          buffer2[nb_read - 1] = '\r';
          buffer2[nb_read] = '\n';
          buffer2[nb_read + 1] = '\0';
          fprintf(stderr,"buffer2 = %s\n", buffer2);
          cpybuffer = strdup(buffer2);                                            
          write(sock, cpybuffer, nb_read + 2);
          memset(buffer2, '\0', 1024);
          free(cpybuffer);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: The password should be sent as `PASS password` -- are you sending it this way?

Comment: When reading from a socket never expect to read as may bytes as your as you told to read.

Comment: You did read this https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt, didn't you?-)

Comment: Why would you expect a `select()` problem to cause FTP commands to fail on the server side?  Please show the actual commands you are sending.

Comment: I send my user like this "user login" then the server answer : "331 Password required for login" and for the pass i enter "pass paswd" or "PASS passwd". Then always the same error 500.